# Static variables inside function and dynamic linkage

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, platform-specific

If I have, for example, following singleton construction inlined in headers:

```
class singleton_t
{
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<singleton_t> instance()
        {
            static std::shared_ptr<singleton_t>
                                 instance{new singleton_t};
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        singleton_t()
        {

        }    
}
```

That are included in several Shared libraries (DLL/SO) and Executables linked dynamically (using `LoadLibrary` / `dlopen`) can I count on to have exactly one singleton instance per module (at least on Windows, Linux, and OS X)?

So, for example:

- `file1.dll` code contains one singleton instance,
- `file2.dll` code contains another instance
- `file3.exe` contains another instance

If `file3.exe` calls function (via `GetProcAddress`) from `file1.dll`, can I count on accessing `file1.dll`'s singleton instance in that function body?

I know C++ standard does not say anything about dynamic linkage, I am looking for platform-specific knowlege. The linkage will be only dynamic.

Comment: why do you use a `shared_ptr` ? If it is a function local static variable there is no way the ref counter ever reaches 0 before your program ends and there is no need to manage ownership. Do I miss something?

Comment: @user463035818 C++ clearly states that static local variables in function body dies on exiting from `main` in undefined order. This tricks allows me ensure the singleton will die last, if - for some reason - destructor of other things requires living instance of it (acquired earlier on)

Comment: You may have one singleton per library, but on Linux, it may only load one at a time because link is done when the app is run. Then sometimes, you may have calls to one singleton, and sometimes to another. Not sure on Windows. Basically, bad idea, One Definition Rule. Change the names of your singletons if you need 3.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I will dynamically load module when the app is already running (inside main). Is it still a problem?

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clarifiying. Btw I think destruction order is defined to be the reverse of initialization, though order or initialization is undefined or hard to control or I dont know what

Comment: @user463035818 Initialization of static variables in function is happening on their first use :)

Comment: @PiotrK most definitely, yes.You may be able to solve the issue if you are not exporting this symbol, in that case, all links should be solved inside each library and not rely on external links.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am actually exporting really small subset of API (the libraries are plugins, actually), and this symbol is definitely internal to given library.

Comment: Then I **think** it's OK on all platforms. Make sure on Linux and macOS to use visibility hidden.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I also think it's OK... But I am not 100% sure, hence the question :)